# IF Statment in Visualforce <apex:selectlist>

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have inherited a visualforce page used as a service form online. The three item values "1-10 toestellen" ect are rendered in 5 languages for different business areas. I need to know if there is a way to display only one of the options for one particular language.

For example, IF (Currentpage.language == 'NL') then only show one option from the list).  Else show them all.

There is a wrapper class called sfw that hold all the variables and I believe there is an Apex class for the business rules.

I can delete the translations in the custom fields but this does not solve my issues

```
                    <apex:outputlabel for="equipmentAmount" value="{!$Label.Amount_of_Equipment}*:" /><br/>
                    <apex:selectList id="equipmentAmount" value="{!sfw.equipmentAmount}" size="1">

                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="--" itemLabel="--"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1-10 toestellen" itemLabel="{!$Label.X1_10_pieces_of_Equipment}" />
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="10-25 toestellen" itemLabel="{!$Label.X10_25_pieces_of_Equipment}" />
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="25+ toestellen" itemLabel="{!$Label.X25_pieces_of_Equipment}" />
                    </apex:selectList>
```

Thank you

Andrew

Comment: how are you planning to determine user language? is that based on user account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you have a variable in your controller called language, you can use the rendered Property like this:

```
<apex:outputlabel for="equipmentAmount" value="{!$Label.Amount_of_Equipment}*:" /><br/>
  <apex:selectList id="equipmentAmount" value="{!sfw.equipmentAmount}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="--" itemLabel="--"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1-10 toestellen" itemLabel="{!$Label.X1_10_pieces_of_Equipment}" rendered="{!language == '' || language == 'NL'}" />
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="10-25 toestellen" itemLabel="{!$Label.X10_25_pieces_of_Equipment}" rendered="{!language == '' || language == 'NL'}" />
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="25+ toestellen" itemLabel="{!$Label.X25_pieces_of_Equipment}" rendered="{!language == '' || language == 'NL'}" />
  </apex:selectList>
```

You would then need each of those options for everylangauge.  In the rendered property, the only part you would need to change is the 'NL'.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a controller flag to decide language. Then use rendered attribute in  tag to hide/show that particular option. Depending on your usecase, you may need more than one flag in controller side and use a combination of these boolean flags to show/hide option from page